# Can C function parameters set variables?

Tags: c, function, parameters

I can't figure out how the firstname and lastname variables are being set in the below C code.

```
printf("Hello, %s, %s\n", firstname, lastname);
```

It looks the char [s] parameter of the readln function is setting firstname & lastname.

Is this possible, if so what is this called so I can do a bit of research.

Thanks

Edit: Below is a simpler version. It looks like the parameter is setting a variable.

```
int foo(char s[]){
    s[0]='w';
    s[1]='\0';

    return 5;
}

int main() {

    char name[2];
    int wtf;

    wtf = foo(name);
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

Parameter char s[] is setting name

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRLEN 5


int readln(char s[], int maxlen) {
    char ch;
    int i;
    int chars_remain;
    i = 0;
    chars_remain = 1;
    while (chars_remain) {
        ch = getchar();
        if ((ch == '\n') || (ch == EOF) ) {
            chars_remain = 0;
        } else if (i < maxlen - 1) {
            s[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char firstname[STRLEN];
    char lastname[STRLEN];
    int len_firstname;
    int len_lastname;
    printf("Enter your first name:");
    len_firstname = readln(firstname, STRLEN);
    printf("Enter your last name:");
    len_lastname = readln(lastname, STRLEN);
    printf("Hello, %s, %s\n", firstname, lastname);
    printf("Length of firstname = %d, lastname = %d", len_firstname, len_lastname);
}
```

Comment: Pass by reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array as an argument to a function, it's exactly like passing the array address. Then, the function can modify the context of this address, means the array itself.

E.g the function can be defined as `int readln(char *s, int maxlen)` and the functionality will stay the same.

When calling the function you could use either `readln(firstname, STRLEN)` or `readln(&firstname[0], STRLEN)`. Both will work with either of the function definitions (they're orthogonal).

A nice [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm) about this subject.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. To clarify this silliness is only for arrays?

Comment: Yeah, the behavior is a bit confusing for arrays. If you pass primitives or structs and don't use the `&` they will be passed by value, unlike arrays.

Comment: @seamus  Re: "only for arrays?" Functions are also converted to a _pointer to the function_ when used as a function parameter (and other situations):  `foo(rand)`.  Yet the receiving function `foo(int (*f)())` cannot certainly read nor write the function `rand()` via that pointer. It can execute the function.

Comment: @SHG "it's exactly like passing the array address. "  --> Almost.  "it's exactly like passing the address of the first element of the array."  This difference is subtle to see.  The value of those 2 address are _equivalent_, yet differ in type and rarely bit pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The general term is "pass by reference" - the formal parameter `s` in `readln` *refers* to the same chunk of memory that the actual parameters `firstname` and `lastname` do in the respective function calls.

C actually passes all function arguments *by value* - the formal parameter in the function definition is a separate object in memory from the actual parameter in the function call, and the value of the actual parameter is copied to the formal parameter:

```
void swap( int a, int b ) // a receives a *copy* of x's value, b receives
{                         // a *copy* of y's value
  int t = a;              // updates to a and b have no effect on x and y
  a = b;
  b = t;
}

void bar( void )
{
   int x = 1, y = 2;
   swap( x, y );          // x and y are not actually updated
}
```

We *fake* pass by reference semantics by passing a pointer to the object we want modified:

```
void swap( int *a, int *b ) // a receives the *address* of x, b receives the
{                           // address of y
  int t = *a;               // updates to *a and *b *do* have and effect on
  *a = *b;                  // x and y
  *b = t;
}

void bar( void )
{
  int x = 1, y = 2;
  swap( &x, &y );          // instead of passing the *values* of x and y,
}                          // we pass their addresses.
```

Again, `a` and `b` are separate objects in memory from `x` and `y`, but instead of receiving the *values* of `x` and `y`, they receive their *addresses*.  IOW

```
 a == &x;
 b == &y;
*a ==  x;
*b ==  y;
```

The situation gets a little weird with arrays - unless it's the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators (or a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration), an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

So, if you pass an array expression to a function, what the function actually receives is a pointer to the first element of the array, so you don't need to use the `&` operator in the function call.  That's what's happening in `readln`; the parameter `s` points to the first element of the array in the function call.