# Passing array into function pointer (in c)?

Tags: c, function-pointers, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, runge-kutta

What I'm trying to do is to solve a second order ODE using Runge Kutta. I have the outlines of the RK method, and the ODE itself built up, but I can't proceed further. I have the ODE-s in an array, and I tried passing this array to the RK, but at the f(dy[i]) parts it gives "expected double* but type double instead" error. And when I tried dividing the two ODE-s into two functions, and passing those to RK, it only worked with the first one. Passing the elements of dy instead of function pointers are not an option, as the RK itself should be able to solve an ODE containing any number of variables.

How can I properly add the array and work with it?
Here is my corresponding piece of code:

```
double* harmOsc(double* p, double t, double* y, double* dy, int n)
{
    double k = p[0];
    double m = p[1];
    double x = y[0];
    double v = y[1];
    dy[0] = v;
    dy[1] = -k/m*x;
    return(dy);
}


double* HarmOsc1(double* dy, double t)
{
    return(dy);
}


void RK4(
    double t,       //independent variable
    double dt,      //stepsize

    double *y,      //variables
    double *dy,     //derivatives
    int n,          //number of equations
    double* (*f)(double*, double))
{

    int j;
    double* l = (double*)calloc(4*n,sizeof(double));
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        l[0*n+j] = dt*f(dy[j],t);
        l[1*n+j] = dt*f(dy[j]+0.5*l[0*n+j],t+0.5*dt);
        l[2*n+j] = dt*f(dy[j]+0.5*l[1*n+j],t+0.5*dt);
        l[3*n+j] = dt*f(dy[j]+0.5*l[2*n+j],t+0.5*dt);
        y[j] = y[j] + (l[0*n+j] + 2*l[1*n+j] + 2*l[2*n+j] + l[3*n+j])/6;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double* p = (double*)calloc(2,sizeof(double));
    p[0] = 15; p[1] = 140;
    double* y = (double*)calloc(2,sizeof(double));
    y[0] = 12.4; y[1] = 1.1;
    double t=0;

    double* dy = (double*)calloc(2,sizeof(double));
    dy = harmOsc(p,t,y,dy,2);
    dy = HarmOsc1(dy,t);

    RK4(t,0.05,p,y,dy,2,&HarmOsc1);
    printf("%f, %f\n",dy[1],dy[0]);
}
```

The HarmOsc1 is the function I call in, so that it has the required amount of parameters.

And of course the warnings I get:

> RK3.c:55:13: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘f’
>
> RK3.c:55:13: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
>
> RK3.c:56:6: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘f’
>
> RK3.c:56:6: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
>
> RK3.c:57:6: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘f’
>
> RK3.c:57:6: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
>
> RK3.c:58:6: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘f’
>
> RK3.c:58:6: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’

Comment: It would help if you clarify what function call the compiler is rejecting.

Comment: Not directly related, but `(1/6)` is an integer division and the result is truncated to 0.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat fixing that. Also, editing to show what is happening

Comment: Your f expects a double*, you give a double. That is what the compiler complains about, that is what your code does. Please explain what is confusing you.

Comment: What confusing me is how to overcome that and get it working. As I've said, passing simply double isn't an option, I must pass an array and get it work with it

Comment: You are calculating a double value to feed to the first paramter. What kind of array are you thinking of? What is the function supposed to do? I admit that the technical terms you used are unclear to me.

Comment: For those of us whose study of differential equations was (ahem) a long time ago, and who also happen not to be psychic, could you explain what the *intent* of this code is?  I mean, would did you *think* you were passing as the first function argument?

Comment: Can you use a local array[2], fill it with the two values the function accesses and then feed the address of the array? How would the second member of the array be calculated?

Comment: Also, where does your `harmOsc()` function fit in?  It's not called directly by `RK4()`, and it's not of the correct type to be the function pointed to by `RK4()`'s `f`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about putting this whole RK into a for and go through all dy[k]-s.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Damn, I missed that! OP, please make a [mcve].

Comment: The Runge-Kutta is a method for numerical integration, which here it should do, namely numerically integrate the equations of motion of the harmonic oscillator. In the first function I have the two ODE-s determined, one that equals to dx/dt = v, and the other is dv/dt = -k/m*x. The RK should be integrating these.

Comment: @NicoleJudge, if that's supposed to be a response to me, it's not what I'm asking about.  I'm asking what you think your code *means*, or at least what you intended it to mean.  "An implementation of RK4" is not a useful answer.

Comment: Double multiplied by pointer to double? I doubt that. MCVE please.

Comment: HarmOsc1 is what is given as f? What do we need HarmOsc for? MCVE please.

Comment: Sorry about that. My code (theoretically) should accept the array of ODE-s and integrate them all. I'm adding the main function now.

Comment: I think you will need to define a maximum number of array entries or somehow provide the dynamic size. E.g. by introducing another parameter.

Comment: When you solved the type problems with the parameters to f(), you will next get problems with the type of the return value. `dt*f(...)` multiplies the doube "dt"  by the return value of f, which is pointer to double.

Comment: @NicoleJudge, adding more code is helping only a little.  I will try to help you help us.  Correct me where I'm wrong: (1) your function RK4 is intended to solve `n` ODEs of the form y' = f(t, y(t)), y(t0) = y0, where each `y` is a scalar-valued function of one (scalar) variable. ...

Comment: Maybe you want this line: `l[0*n+j] = dt* (*(f(&dy[j],t)));`. This one passes to `f` a pointer to double and then multiply the value *in the* returned address with another double, which is a valid multiplication.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, it is so

Comment: ... (2) parameter `t` to your `RK4()` function is `t0`, the start of the interval over which you are computing solutions.  (3) `dt` is the spacing between sample points for your solutions (i.e. the step size).  (4) `n` is the number of equations you want to solve, which is also the dimension of the arrays pointed to by `p`, `y`, and `dy`.

Comment: ... (5) I suspect that `y` is supposed to be an array of the values of your functions `y` for argument `t`, but you do not use it.  (6) `dy` is an array that seems to be meant to receive the estimated value of each function at time `t` + `dt`, contrary to your comment that it is for the derivatives.

Comment: ... And I'm afraid a cannot figure out what `p` is supposed to represent, but maybe that's OK, because you don't use that either.

Comment: p is only for holding the parameters k and m, so yes, it's irrelevant there, deleting it. And it seems I mixed up the y and dy vectors, I should fix those

Comment: @SHG that fixes it in that line, but in the other ones it generates another error

Comment: Of course, you should apply the same fix for the other lines as well (second line should be `l[1*n+j] = dt* (*(f(&dy[j]+0.5*l[0*n+j],t+0.5*dt)));` and so on..). But before that, if you have logic problems you should fix these first (i.e. mixing up `y` and `dy` vectors).

Comment: @SHG sorry to be unclear, applying that fix to the other lines generates an "invalid operands to binary + (have ‘double *’ and ‘double’)" error

Comment: @NicoleJudge, you said "yes" to my guess that "your function RK4 is intended to solve n ODEs of the form y' = f(t, y(t)), y(t0) = y0, where each y is a scalar-valued function of one (scalar) variable."  However, the `HarmOsc1()` function you are passing in is inappropriate for that.  It appears to provide for each `y` to be a vector-valued function of an unspecified number of variables (or maybe of one vector-valued variable).  What gives?

Comment: I edited my comment because of brackets. See now my previous comment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the nature of your program, but I think you get *passing arrays to function* a bit wrong. I've just [answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901087/can-c-function-parameters-set-variables/43901468#43901468) about it a few days ago, maybe it will be useful.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I totally lost you there.. as far as I see, HarmOsc1() doesn't do anything with y. I'm starting to give up this program, I got totally lost.

Comment: @NicoleJudge, I think you *did* get totally lost, but I think I also have enough to write an answer that will help.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would be really grateful if you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on clarifications provided in comments, we have established that your function `RK4()` is supposed to use the Runge-Kutta method to numerically solve one value of each of several ODEs of the form

```
y'(t) = f(y(t), t)
```

with initial value conditions of the form

```
y(t0) = y0
```

Where `t` is a scalar and each `y` is scalar-valued, and the `f()` is the same for all the ODEs (or at least is represented by the same C function).

We furthermore established that the function parameters have these meanings:

```
t    equivalent to t0 above
dt   the distance from t to the point at which the solutions are to be computed
y    points to an array in which to return the solutions
dy   points to the initial function values (y0 above) for all the ODEs
n    the number of ODEs to solve
f    the function `f()` above
```

You have a variety of problems, but I think most of them ultimately start with your declaration of `RK4()`'s parameter `f`.  Note in particular that the above form for the ODEs requires `f()` to accept as arguments one value of the same dimension as each `y`'s value and another of the same dimension / number as each `y`'s arguments, and to return a value of the same dimension as each `y`'s value.  But we have established that the `y`s are *scalar* functions of *one scalar* argument each, so `f` should accept two `double`s and return one `double`.  That would get us to this declaration:

```
void RK4(
    double t,       //initial point
    double dt,      //delta
    double *y,      //result values
    double *dy,     //initial values
    int n,          //number of equations
    double (*f)(double, double)) {
```

You don't need `f` to compute results for multiple ODEs in one run because your `RK4()` iterates over the ODEs and calls `f()` separately for each one.

Next, let's look at your variable `l`.  You are dynamically allocating enough space to store all four RK constants for each input ODE (and not freeing it), but this is useless.  You use each set of RK constants only once, so you do not need to remember previous ones when you move on to the next equation.  Thus, you only need space for four constants, and since that's a fixed number, you do not need dynamic allocation.  You don't even really get any benefit from using an array; I would just use four scalar variables, declared inside the loop body.

```
    int j;
    // double* l = (double*)calloc(4*n,sizeof(double));
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        double k1 = dt * f(dy[j], t);
        double k2 = dt * f(dy[j] + 0.5 * k1, t + 0.5 * dt);
        double k3 = dt * f(dy[j] + 0.5 * k2, t + 0.5 * dt);
        double k4 = dt * f(dy[j] + k3, t + dt);  // <-- note corrections
```

Observe that the argument and return types with which `f` is now declared match the requirements of the RK equations for the form of the input ODEs.

Finally, compute the result:

```
        y[j] = dy[j] + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6;
```

NOTE WELL the essential difference between that last line and your version -- RK computes a delta y, but your initial y values are in *`dy`*, not in `y`.

And that's it:

```
    }
}
```

I observe at this point that the biggest problems I had in addressing your question arose from not understanding the details of what you were trying to do.  This arose from several things, large among them

- Your variable and parameter names are short and unexpressive, and worse, to the extent that they *seem* to mean something, several of them actually represent something different than their names suggest
- The code documentation is minimal and apparently incorrect.  This seems to go a bit with the previous point, as the function parameter naming makes a bit more sense in light of the limited (but not entirely correct) parameter documentation.
- The code itself was of limited help, because of the very flaws that prompted the question.

Take home: *write **good** code documentation*.  Use full sentences.  Describe each function's expectations for each parameter, and what it promises to do with them.  Describe the return value.  Document any error handling the function performs.  As you do this, try to think like someone who wants to use your function, but can't consult its implementation to see what it does -- what does that person need to know?  In fact, I recommend writing  documentation for each function before writing that function's implementation.  Do update the docs as you discover need, but the docs can help keep you on track, and writing them first can help with writing as if you can't see the implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!! I'm breaking down your code and working on mine. As soon as it is operational, I'll mark the question as solved by your answer.

Comment: It is working now as intended. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: It should be noted that there is only one differential equation of second order in the question, the helper function `HarmOsc1` should have the role to encapsulate the passing of the parameters `p` of the ODE function `harmOsc` (which should actually be called in that function). Your code is good for uncoupled scalar ODE, but the order 1 system of the harmonic oscillator is very well coupled, so that your code does nothing to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The function `f` is expecting a `double *`, i.e. a pointer to a `double` for its first parameter.  However, in each place you call `f`, you're passing a `double` value, not a pointer to a `double` nor an array (which decays to a pointer to the first value):

```
    // here ------------v
    l[0*n+j] = dt*f(  dy[j],                 t);
    l[1*n+j] = dt*f(  dy[j]+0.5*l[0*n+j],    t+0.5*dt);
    l[2*n+j] = dt*f(  dy[j]+0.5*l[1*n+j],    t+0.5*dt);
```

If the first parameter to this function needs to be an array, then pass it an array, not a single value.

Comment: I cannot change it to accept a double, as the RK method written should be universal and working with a random number of variables. How exactly do you mean the second option?

Comment: @NicoleJudge If the function expects an array, then pass it an array, not just one value.

Answer (score 0):

f is expecting that the first argument is double*, while you call f with dy[j], which is a double.
Simply changing dy[j] to dy + j should work.

or

You might need one temp variable

```
double tempv;
```

then inside the loop,

```
tempv = dy[j];
...
tempv = dy[j] + ...;
```

call f with the address of tempv,

```
f(&tempv,...)
```

Comment: What you suggest would fix the type mismatch, but I'm willing to be that it wouldn't produce the desired result.

Comment: I guess I see where this is going, I might give it a try

Answer (score 0):

In C it is not advisable to return arrays. It is possible, but a hassle to manage what code is responsible for freeing this memory. Also, it is against some C philosophy of producing high performance code to needlessly generate repeatedly essentially the same array only to have it destroyed shortly thereafter. You can do that when prototyping algorithms in script languages.

Thus it is better to have the derivative function have signature

```
void f( double * dy, double * y, double t);
```

where dimension and constants are external constants (or add on a parameter array to the list of arguments)

Then you use that in the rk4 loop as

```
f(k1,  y, t      );
for(i=0; i<n; i++) yt[i] = y[i] + 0.5*h*k1[i];
f(k2, yt, t+0.5*h);
for(i=0; i<n; i++) yt[i] = y[i] + 0.5*h*k2[i];
f(k3, yt, t+0.5*h);
for(i=0; i<n; i++) yt[i] = y[i] +     h*k3[i];
f(k4, yt, t+h);
for(i=0; i<n; i++) y[i] = y[i] + h/6*(k1[i]+2*(k2[i]+k3[i])+k4[i]);
```

Of course you will want to ensure that you allocate the `k1,k2,k3,k4,yt` also only once per integration. This can happen in 3 ways:

- the integration procedure contains the full loop, returning a list of points if necessary,
- there is some structure containing the work arrays that is constructed before the first integration step,
- or you use the newer dynamic stack allocation that should also not have a prohibitive allocation penalty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please explain, why you are using y[i] and not yt[i] in the additions? (etc yt[i] = y[i] + 0.5*h*k1[i];)

Comment: Because the offsets are all from the basis point of the step. As there is no operator overloading in `C`, you have to perform the vector operations in `k2=f(y+0.5*h*k1,t+0.5*h)` beforehand, so that pass by pointer or reference is possible.